# How can I deploy a django application to multiple servers efficiently?

Tags: nginx, deployment, automation, django

What are a few options to deploy changes made to a django project to multiple servers simultaneously in an efficient manner?

Are there any tools that would allow servers to checkout latest changes from a repository, restart apache or nginx, etc?

Answer (score 2):

[fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/) is a quite nice tool that you could use.

See this [blogpost](http://lethain.com/entry/2008/nov/04/deploying-django-with-fabric/) for more info about deploying django with [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/).
or [this](http://morethanseven.net/2009/07/27/fabric-django-git-apache-mod_wsgi-virtualenv-and-p.html) or [this](https://launchpad.net/django-fabric).

Comment: most links are outdated, could the author plz update?